# Join array with svg in jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I perform the following with jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { ReactComponent as Img } from "./4ddd.svg";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return <div className="App">{[1, 2, 3].join(<Img />)}</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

This gives

[image]

The desired output is

[image]

What is the right way to join the array with svg icon?

Please see the code at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-nova-5fjg9r)

Answer (score 2):

`join` is expecting string join, but you're using a component, so that's why it shows `[object Object]`. You can do it with `reduce` instead

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-night-8ud9dz?file=/src/index.js:0-376)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { ReactComponent as Img } from "./4ddd.svg";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
return <div className="App">{[1, 2, 3].reduce((current, value) => [current, <Img/>, value])}</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This gives what we expect, but the output array is deeply nested. it can be made a 1 dimension arrray like this `{[2, 3].reduce((current, value) => [...current, <Img />, value], [1])}`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `map` instead of `join` in this way:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {[1, 2, 3].map((x) => (
        <div className="Align">
          {x}
          {x !== [1, 2, 3].length && <Img />}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

And a little bit of css to keep all aligned:

```
.Align {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-antonelli-j37e75?file=/src/index.js) your codesandbox modified.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { ReactComponent as Img } from "./4ddd.svg";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const numberArr = [1, 2, 3];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {numberArr.map((item, index) => (
        <>
          {item}
          {index < numberArr.length - 1 && <Img />}
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here code: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-drake-db64xk?file=/src/index.js:0-477